# How to insert an array of objects (bulk-insert) into neo4j with bolt protocol (javascript)

Tags: javascript, neo4j, bulkinsert

1.Send an http post with objects array to server

```
[{id:1, title: ‘one’},
{id:2, title:’two’}]
```

2.Receive post on server and bulk insert into neo4j with bolt

```
    let data = req.body;
    //set up bolt
    let db      = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
    let driver  = db.driver('bolt://localhost', db.auth.basic('neo4j', ’neo4j’));
    let session = driver.session();
```

3. Set up statements for execution

```
    // start transaction
    for(var i=0; i>data.length; i++) {
     //add CREATE statements to bolt session ???
    "CREATE (r:Record {id:1, title:'one'})"
    "CREATE (r:Record {id:2, title:'two'})"
    ...
    }

    //execute session.run(???);
    //stop transaction
```

Comment: I am also interested in finding answer to the same question. If you found a solution please post it here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In step 3, you can pass your entire input `list` (from step 1) as a parameter. (However, if the input list is very long, you should split it into smaller batches -- say of 10,000 items each.)

For example:

```
session
  .run(
    "UNWIND {list} AS i CREATE (:Record {id: i.id, title: i.title})",
    { list: list })
  .then(function(result){

    // Use the result ...

    session.close();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```