# Insert records from list into Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j

I am using c# 3.1 Neo4j driver with Bolt. I am not using the neo4jclient because I am using bolt.

I need to insert a list of records List into Neo4j.

```
public class Patient
{
     public string PatientId { get; set;}
     public string PatientKey { get; set;}
     public string PatientFN { get; set;}
     public string PatientLN { get; set;}
     public DateTime PatientDOB { get; set;}
}
```

So I have a List... I have been looking at UNWIND but don't quite understand how to do it with a object list.

```
List<Patient> patients = GetPatients();

IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://myserver:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("user", "password"));

using (var session = driver.Session())
{
     session.Run("UNWIND...")
}
```

I don't want to use a foreach loop. And I don't want to use a csv file.

I found an answer that I think is pretty close but it is for Java. [java response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828785/how-to-insert-an-array-of-objects-bulk-insert-into-neo4j-with-bolt-protocol-j)

Can someone help me with the cypher command?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you reading an input from a non-Neo4j source and wanting to add nodes, relationships or properties to your Neo4j database?

Comment: Correct. We are doing a proof of concept and want to test adding data to neo4j.